# How does Closure work? is object or function?

Tags: php, closures

a object!!!, not is function!!! , a method?, how does it work?

```
var_dump(is_object(function(){}));//true 
var_dump(class_exists("Closure"));//true
//var_dump(new Closure());//Error Instantiation of class Closure is not allowed
var_dump(is_callable(function(){}));//true 
var_dump(method_exists(function(){},'__invoke'));//true
var_dump(new ReflectionMethod(function(){},'__invoke'));//object  Closure __Invoke
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Closure,how does it work?

Comment: In PHP, Closure is the built-in class for anonymous functions.

Comment: suggested reading [no, php does not have closures](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2019/09/25/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.